# Yii automatic db migrations

Tags: php, database-migration, yii

I have setup my first db migration using the built in migration tools of yii, and locally i can run

./yiic migrate

I can see it say "this migration needs to run" and press Y and it runs and works fine.

When i deploy my site, I can automatically run that command but not pass the Y

Is there a command or url i can hit to upgrade the db without logging in and pressing Y?

Answer (score 36, accepted):

Yes, use the command: `./yiic migrate --interactive=0` and it will run without prompting you.

See http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/1.1/en/database.migration#use-command-line-options for more details.

Answer (score 4):

For some reason this wasn't working in 1.1.8, so i added the following to the console config file.

```
'commandMap'=> array(
    'migrate'=> array(
      'class'=>'system.cli.commands.MigrateCommand',
      'interactive'=> 0,
    ),
),
```

Comment: you should use 0 instead of the string "false", see http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/1.1/en/database.migration#c2789